# SAGA tools not working in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, saga, qgis-2.18

I've only just started using QGIS (done some things in ArcGIS before) and SAGA tools don't work. The results don't make sense, QGIS stops answering or there is a python error.
Could it be that there is something wrong with the installation? Or do I need to learn some python to fix it?

Comment: Are you using Windows, OS X or Linux?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: I would recommend you to install [OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) to properly use SAGA inside QGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Saga function?  What version of SAGA? 
Probably something to do with projection and/or resolution. If you are using EPSG:4326 then you must use the resolution in degrees ie 
0.0001 
[Degrees to meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees)

Comment: I want to interpolate some data, so I tried different Kriging methods as well as other raster creation tools. Since they don't work I also tried simpler ones like statistics for raster.

Comment: I use Saga 2.3.2

Comment: Try changing the output resolution as said above. And post the output (in the processing -> history tab)